# How to reduce maximum power rating of dishwasher for use with photovoltaics inverter?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, power

I have a photovoltaic power system and an inverter with an overall power rating of 1500 Watts. I want to connect a dishwasher which consumes 2200 Watts when heating the water.

**Question:** What is the best way to reduce this maximum power rating of the dishwasher? Is it possible to somehow (how?) use a voltage divider or a simple resistor in series with the heating coil?

I assume the only drawback of this idea would be that the washing takes longer, as the water needs more time to heat up.

Answer (score 2):

From an efficiency standpoint you would be way better off to use the sun to heat the water up instead of converting to electricity in the middle of the process. Modify the dishwasher to accept the solar heated water instead of dumping any electricity into the heater coil.

To get even more efficient adopt a washing strategy with cold water cleaning in a basin followed by drying in the sun.

Comment: Some dishwashers do have switches to turn off the heater coil for both wash and dry cycles.